# enable networking between two different subnets without router

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking

I have a centOS machine (10.0.0.4), which is running two vagrant boxes, 10.0.2.15 and 10.0.3.15. 
Is it possible to enable networking between these two vagrant boxes?

## for 10.0.2.15

```
route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.219.64  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
192.168.219.68  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 calibe3d69d2768


ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c9:c7:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85785sec preferred_lft 85785sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec9:c704/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c7:8e:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.10/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fec7:8e4c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:fc:ea:65:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: calibe3d69d2768@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1440 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    inet 192.168.219.64/32 brd 192.168.219.64 scope global tunl0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## For 10.0.3.15

```
route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.3.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0


ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c9:c7:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.15/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85457sec preferred_lft 85457sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec9:c704/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:93:4b:93:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## For 10.0.0.1

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
168.63.129.16   10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0

ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:06:5e:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.4/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fe06:5ecf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:45:a0:80:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:45ff:fea0:805a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vetheefdb4e@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP
    link/ether de:7d:18:e9:25:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::dc7d:18ff:fee9:25e9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: veth6665af6@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP
    link/ether ba:db:33:b6:56:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::b8db:33ff:feb6:5688/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.1/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decrease the netmask on each side to /23 they'll talk to each other without a router (providing they're bridged together).

Another approach is to configure a second IP address from the other subnet on at least one of the boxes or move it over altogether (both also require bridging).

Otherwise, you'll need a router.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can give IP's to your host from each of the guests subnets, set the host's IP as default GW in guests (each from respective subnet) and activate ip forwarding on the host. This way your host will act as a router.

Option 2: Create a new bridge just for those 2 boxes and connect them using a new network

I see that you're using x.x.x.2 as default gateways. To whom does that IP belong? Something is also not consistent in your config, considering that your host has an ip addr from 10.0.2.0/24 but not from 10.0.3.0/24... maybe I'm missing something.